# Add static images to MP4 container using MediaMuxer

Tags: android, mp4, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

The MP4 container apparently supports including static images on tracks. I was not able to determine whether Android's MediaMuxer was capable of supporting this. I could encode the images as part of video encoding processing that I carry out using MediaCodec, but I would prefer to add the images during the muxing stage.

It should be noted that I'm using mp4 as a video. But logically, I' guessing that it should be possible to define an image track and insert static images that are rendered at their respective presentation times.

Is this possible using the MediaMuxer?

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer#addTrack(android.media.MediaFormat)) list the supported track types and format keys across android releases.

TLDR: only video and audio tracks are supported my `MediaMuxer`.